# Error no such table in iphone sqlite select query?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am having tabbed iPhone application.In the first tab I created sqlite table and inserted values to the table,these are done successfully.In the second tab  I am able to get the values from table but in third class when I am executing the select query, I am getting the no such table exception.
Even I deleted the app from simulator and cleaned the project,but I got the same problem.
Kindly give me solutions.

**Coding for create and insert:**

```
-(void)InsertLoginDetails:(NSString *)user fun:(NSString *)pwd{

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO Login ( USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\")",
                           user, pwd];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,
                       -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Inserted");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to insert");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}
```

}

```
-(void)createLoginTable{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Build the path to the database file
_databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                  @"login.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Login (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"Failed to create table");

        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
        NSLog(@"Table created");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");

    }
}
```

}

**Code for getting values:**

```
-(void)checkLoginSession{
///////////////GET DB DATAS///////////////////////

const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM Login";


    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            strDBUsername = [[NSString alloc]
                             initWithUTF8String:
                             (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                statement, 0)];
            strDBPwd = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                        sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            NSLog(@"Settings page Login Details %@ %@", strDBUsername , strDBPwd );
            //                _address.text = addressField;
            //
            //                _phone.text = phoneField;
            //                _status.text = @"Match found";
        } else {
            //                _status.text = @"Match not found";
            //                _address.text = @"";
            //                _phone.text = @"";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"SQLITE NOT OK");
        NSLog(@"Error %s ", sqlite3_errmsg(_contactDB));
    }
    sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
}
```

Comment: Looking forward your suggestions.

Comment: Please put the related code, else how can we identify the problem ?

Comment: Put the code which you are working on.

Comment: Please delete the application and install again.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy just reset the simulator but didn't work for me

Comment: @MidhunMP i posted my coding

Comment: @Manimaran i posted my source code.

Comment: @Kalai You don't need to reset the simulator. Just delete the application and re-install the application.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy yes i tried..but it wont work :(

Comment: Please log the database path (using `NSLog()`) in **all** three cases and ensure they all match.

Comment: Also forget about the `fileExistsAtPath` check; sqlite will create the database if it doesn't exist and your code is basically assuming that the existence of the database is the same as the existence of the table.  This is not true.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes you are right.My database paths returns as null.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry for asking this question.How to solve the database path as null error?

Comment: You should initialize `_databasePath` **once** and probably within one of the early app-delegate methods.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry for the interruption..I just solved that database path to null issue but it throws the no such table error.

Comment: and did you remove the `fileExistsAtPath` check?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes i removed fileExistsAtPath condition..Unfortunately it is also not working for me.